# How to share my data to facebook in drupal?

Tags: facebook, module, drupal-7

> Hai Guys,
>
> I am new to Drupal.Here I am using Drupal 7.I installed fb.module.And i have one tpl file with some data.Now i want to share that data with facebook.Is it possible?
>
> Please any one help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RSS to share your website updates

1. At Drupal side, you build your rss with views
2. At Facebook side, you can use RSS graffiti for example to aggregate
   datas